# How do pools determine a pool-user's hashrate?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-shares, hashpower

How do pools determine a pool-user's hashrate? It seems they would base it on the particular user's difficulty or rate of accepted shares.

Comment: @Murch: How so? I'm looking for a formula pools could use to calculate it.

Comment: It appears that your intended request is more specific than the question you have presented us, as the answer I linked gives an overview of what you appear to be asking here, and names four different methods of distributing the mining reward. Perhaps you should clarify what you already know, and what information on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Murch: Yes, my question is exactly a duplicate of your 2nd link.